# windows 10 - firewall IP based rules

Tags: windows, firewall, ip, whitelist

I have a long list of IP ranges which I want to whitelist in windows firewall.
I've found how to add a single range, but typing one range at a time will be very hard.
Is there a way to import a list of IP ranges (from a file, or just copy paste), and to use them for multiple rules?
I'm using windows 10.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and include the version of Windows you are using? Windows built in firewall doesn't support defining groups of IP addresses, but there are ways to add rules via PowerShell depending on the version of Windows.

Comment: windows 10. I thought that powershell script could do the job, I'm not familiar with powerhsell though.